# With Next.js 13 Routes API, what are TypeScript declarations for GET?

Tags: node.js, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm trying to not use the `any` type when creating a GET handler with the new Next.js 13 experimental routing API.

Here is my code:

```
export async function GET(request: any, {params}: any) {
  function getRandomInt(min: number, max: number) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); // The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
  }

  const youTubeId = params.id;
```

I've tried `HttpWebResponse` but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return new Response('Hello world')
}
```

`Request` and `Response` are globally available. its type will be inferred as `function GET(request: Request): Promise<Response>`

or you could use `NextResponse`

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message:"success" }, { status: 200 });
}
```

and its type will be inferred as `function GET(request: Request): Promise<NextResponse>`